# issue with php 5.4.23 in intl extension installation

Tags: php, php-5.4

I have `PHP 5.4.23` on my `CentOS with Nginx as webserver`

and I am trying to install `php-intl` extension

I ran below command

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi install php-intl
```

It ran successfully but still my phpinfo don't show this extension...

please help

Comment: Have you checked your php.ini file?

Comment: yes...it is not having line extension=php_intl.dll to uncomment

Comment: Then add it: extension=intl.so